# InvalidOperationException: This cannot be used during play mode, please use SceneManager.CreateNewScene() instead

Tags: unity-game-engine, automation, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

As i am new to unity . I am trying to automate Unity game using unity inbuild tool "Editor Tests runner". I am able to write test cases but when i am running test cases getting below error.

> InvalidOperationException: This cannot be used during play mode, please use SceneManager.CreateNewScene() instead.
>
> UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.NewScene (NewSceneSetup setup, NewSceneMode mode) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorSceneManagerBindings.gen.cs:47)
>
> UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.EditorTestsRunnerWindow.OpenNewScene () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/EditorTestsRunner/UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner/TestRunner/EditorTestsRunnerWindow.cs:392)
>
> UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.EditorTestsRunnerWindow.RunTests (UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.TestRunnerFilter filter) (at 
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/EditorTestsRunner/UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner/TestRunner/EditorTestsRunnerWindow.cs:368)
>
> UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.EditorTestsRunnerWindow.RunTests (NUnit.Core.TestName[] tests) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/EditorTestsRunner/UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner/TestRunner/EditorTestsRunnerWindow.cs:357)
>
> UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.EditorTestsRunnerWindow+c__AnonStorey1.<>m__7 (System.Object data) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/EditorTestsRunner/UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner/TestRunner/EditorTestsRunnerWindow.cs:232)
>
> UnityEditor.GenericMenu.CatchMenu (System.Object userData, System.String[] options, Int32 selected) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/GenericMenuBindings.gen.cs:122)

I am running test cases on Game Play mode.

Comment: Would you like to share your code as well?

Comment: yes sure.. code is copied at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3TIRYVY5uBkNi1jTm5wSmVzZWc

Comment: @UmairM : please check

Comment: Your code doesn't have any kind of information related to exception as this is about SceneManagar. Though you can have a look at : 
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/new-multi-scene-changes-in-5-3-1p4-issues.381338/